# Php form submission - "thank you" message on same page instead of another page?

Tags: php, html, forms, lightbox

I have an html page with a php form submission, it's very basic.. what I am looking to do is as of right now it submits, then goes to a blank page with the words "thank you" etc, but what I am looking to do is when the user submits the form, it pop up a window or lightbox that says "thank you for submitting". How can I achieve this? Here's the form's html code, and the actual php code for the submit.

html code:

```
        <form method="post" action="includes/buy.php">
        <h2> Sizes: </h2><select name="sizes"><option value="1">1</option></select>
        <h2> Email: </h2><input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="hidden" value="black" name="color" />
        <input  type="image" value="submit" src="images/buynow.jpg" />
        </form>
```

php form submission code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = " ";
$email_subject = "subject line here";


function died($error) {
echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

if(!isset($_POST['email'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$email_from = $_POST['email']; 
$color = $_POST['color'];
$sizes = $_POST['sizes'];


$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details:\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Size: ".clean_string($sizes)."\n";
$email_message .= "Color: ".clean_string($color)."\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: You might want to look into doing an ajax call.  For something a bit more easy you could just redirect back to this page with a special message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [**AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Here's an example:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="yourForm" action="">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" class="formSubmit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
$('.formSubmit').on('click', function() {
    var field1 = $('input[name=field1]').val();
    var field2 = $('input[name=field2]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST';
        url: 'yourPHPScript.php?f1='+ field1 +'&f2='+ field2;
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
// proccess the data
die('successful');
```

In PHP file: if something's wrong, just `die()` that result and it will display an `alert()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without a page load (i.e. using pop-up dialog or similar), you would need to look at using AJAX.  However if a reload of the page is fine, you can just use the current page as the page form's target and process the form within the same script.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could choose this and the other guy's as answers, you're both the same idea, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with it popping up in a seperate window you could have your form's target set to _new or _blank. A better solution is to use javascript to submit the form using AJAX, and then displaying the result in the page.

When using JavaScript with AJAX it may be wise to look into jQuery, specifically [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link a quick easy PHP to another .php file

you can do something like

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['field1'];
?>
```

had to read this quick from my phone i am in class, but hope this helps